# How to compare time series with different time stamps

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, stochastic-processes

My data consists of several time series of the form

$A_i = [ (t^i_0,x^i_0), (t^i_1, x^i_1), \ldots, (t^i_{n_i}, x^i_{n_i})]$ for $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots 20 \}$

$B_j = [ (t^j_0,x^j_0), (t^j_1, x^j_1), \ldots, (t^j_{n_j}, x^j_{n_j})]$ for $j \in \{21, 22, \ldots 40 \}$

Where $x \in \mathbb R$ is a measurement taken at time delta $t \in \mathbb R$, measured in milliseconds after some start time $T_0$ which is the same for all series.

My goal is to compare the two sets of time series $\{ A_1, \ldots, A_{20} \}$ and  $\{ B_{21}, \ldots, B
_{40} \}$ and to decide whether they come from the same distribution or not.

If this is too abstract, imagine two algorithms $A$ and $B$.
Each algorithm is run 20 times and, during each run, gathers rewards over time. The algorithm $A$ takes longer than $B$ for each time step, but the rewards are higher.
Both algorithms are run for a fixed time. $A$ will gather less measurements than $B$ in that time.
Which algorithm is now better? Is it $A$, wich had the chance to gather less rewards, but the rewards are overall higher? Or is it $B$, which gathered more but overall lower rewards?

[image]
Look at the following picture where I created an artificial example.
I only drew the first 3 runs of each algorithm to illustrate the problem. On the left, the individual rewards are plotted for each process. On the right, the cumulative sum of all previous rewards are plotted.

Notice that

- Series $A$ have less measurements than $B$ in the same time period
- Series $B$ got lower rewards, but its cumulative reward is higher than that of $A$ due to the higher number of measurements.

The data are generated in numpy with

```
at = np.arange(0, 5.1, 1)
A = [pd.Series((at+np.random.random(at.shape))*10, index=at+ np.random.random(at.shape)) for i in range(3)]
bt = np.arange(0, 5.1, 0.2)
B = [pd.Series((bt+np.random.random(bt.shape))*5, index=bt+np.random.random(bt.shape)) for j in range(3)]
```

The plots indicate that process $B$ is indeed different (and better) than $A$.
But how would a more formal analysis of this statement look?

Comment: It looks to me like you're doing the right thing. In some parts of the optimisation literature you will see plots of the reward gained for every unit of CPU time (or similar). If I were you, I'd produce a plot for the average of $A$ and $B$ at each time point. It should be a clearer plot. I don't think there is much formal analysis to be done. If all you care about is cumulative reward then $B$ beats $A$ in this example. I would also add more replications to the example to be more certain that $B$ beats $A$.

Comment: Makes sense, but when computing average, median etc. I am worried about making implicit assumptions. For example, how should I interpolate between measurements? Linear, step-function etc? Would that even matter for the final analysis or can I make big mistakes here?

Comment: PS: Can you recommend any books on this topic? I am fairly new and would appreciate some starting points for research (also for citation).

Comment: How is the reward you're interested in calculated? Is it the sum of the height of the measurements? Can I rephrase your question as; "Based on these realizations of A and B, can I conclude that the expected value of another realization of A is going to be higher than that of B"?

Comment: @Gijs Question (1): every $x$ is the $\gamma$-discounted return of an episode of a reinforcement learning algorithm in a Markov decision procedure, i.e. $x=G_0 = \sum_{k = 0, 1, \ldots, T} \gamma ^ k R_k $ as explained in [Sutton and Barto 2018](http://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/SuttonBartoIPRLBook2ndEd.pdf) page 55. $x$ and $t$ are measured whenever an episode ends. Then, the next episode is started.
I am interested in the sum of the return over all epiodes up to  some time limit. To your other questions: (2) not sure what you mean by that (3) yes that sounds sensible.